# Sync calls with room

Tags: java, android, android-room, android-livedata

I am learning livedata and room db, but i can't undestand one thing: Document says all room queries should be performed in another thread but some queries that i need should be performed in main thread. Why? **Imagine**: I have a chat app and when a message comes to the app i need to check this message's sender if blocked by app user before showing message to user. So i need to do this in main thread. How to handle this situtations with room?

Ps: I don't want to use `allowMainThreadQueries()` because mostly my queries will be in another thread.

Comment: *Imagine: I have a chat app and when a message comes to the app i need to check this message's sender if blocked by app user before showing message to user. So i need to do this in main thread.* **not true** ... obviously you can do this with one query ... `SELECT ... FROM messages WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM users WHRE messageUserID = userID AND userIsBlocked=1)`

Comment: So if i want to perform a query in main thread then probably am i wrong?

Comment: why you wana do query on main thread at first place?

Comment: `but some queries that i need should be performed in main thread.` that can't be right

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Imagine: I have a chat app

Presumably, this uses a network. Your network I/O had better be on a background thread, as otherwise you have bigger problems.

> ...and when a message comes to the app i need to check this message's sender if blocked by app user before showing message to user.

So, you are on a background thread already when the chat message comes in. You can query the database on that background thread to see if the sender is on the block list.

> So i need to do this in main thread.

No, because your network I/O is on a background thread. Do your is-sender-blocked check on that same thread before delivering the results to the user.

Even if for some reason you wind up on the main application thread with the message before checking the database, you can still check the database on a (different) background thread and only add the message to the UI after that check.